# Convert date column (string) to datetime and match the format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to covert the next date column (str) to datetime64 and say that format doesn't match, can anyone help me pleas :)

Column:

df["Date"]

0       15/7/21
...
2541    13/9/21
dtype: object

What I try:

pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format = "%d/%m/%Y")

ValueError: time data '15/7/21' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)

I also try:

pd.to_datetime(df["Date"].astype("datetime64"), format='%d/%m/%Y')

And it convert it as datetime but there is some date the day is in the month.

Anyone know what to do ?

Answer (score 1):

`%Y` expects a 4-digit year.  Use `%y` for a 2-digit year (See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)):

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['15/7/21','13/9/21']})
>>> df['Date']
0    15/7/21
1    13/9/21
Name: Date, dtype: object
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype('datetime64'),format='%d/%m/%y')
0   2021-07-15
1   2021-09-13
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Note that `pandas` is pretty good at guessing the format:

```py
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
0   2021-07-15
1   2021-09-13
```