# Convert date column (string) to datetime and match the format in Python

Tags: python, date

I have a similar question to this: [Convert date column (string) to datetime and match the format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69488649/convert-date-column-string-to-datetime-and-match-the-format) and I want to convert a string like '12/7/21' to '2021-07-12' as a date object. I believe the answer given in the link above is wrong and here is why:

```py
# The suggested solution on Stackoverflow 
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['15/7/21']})
>>> df['Date']
0    15/7/21
Name: Date, dtype: object
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype('datetime64'),format='%d/%m/%y')
0   2021-07-15
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Because Python doesn't care about the specified format in the above code! If you simply change 15 to 12 and input '12/7/21' then it treats 12 as month instead of day:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['12/7/21']})
>>> df['Date']
0    12/7/21
Name: Date, dtype: object
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype('datetime64'),format='%d/%m/%y')
0   2021-12-07
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Does anyone know what's the best solution to this problem?
(In R you simply use lubridate::dmy(df$Date) and it works perfectly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.astype('datetime64')` attempts to parse the string `MM/DD/YY` however if it can't (in the case that MM > 12) it will fall back to parsing as `DD/MM/YY` this is why you see seemingly inconsistent behaviour:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.Series('15/7/21').astype('datetime64')
0   2021-07-15
dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> pd.Series('14/7/21').astype('datetime64')
0   2021-07-14
dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> pd.Series('13/7/21').astype('datetime64')
0   2021-07-13
dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> pd.Series('12/7/21').astype('datetime64')
0   2021-12-07
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The way to solve this is just to pass a `Series` of strings to [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime) instead of intermediately converting to `datetime64`s. So you can simply do

```py
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%y')
```

without the `.astype` cast

Comment: Thanks @tiger. Is it possible to change multiple columns using pipe instead of doing it one by one by assignment? Like if I want to change multiple columns in different ways it would be a lot of assignments and repetitions of df.

Comment: Yep [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) also supports `DataFrame`s so you can do `pd.to_datetime(df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']], format='%d/%m/%y')` 

However if you have different `format`s you will need to use different assignments for each format.

Comment: Yeah I meant for different formats. In R you can do "df |> mutate(col1 = f_1(col1), col2 = f_2(col2), col3 = f_3(col3))", f_i being some arbitrary transformation, so there is no need for multiple assignments, "mutate" can take as many transformation as you want. I wish Python had a similar feature too, because numerous assignments is horrible.